# query for empty array in "include" model field

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Let’s say I have foo and I make it include bar model,
They are many to many relationship.
While bar model contains a column called clients, which is an array in nodejs.

```
foo.findAll({
    where      : where,
    include    : [{ model: bar}]
})
```

How should I use `foo.findAll` to get all data which `bar` must be an empty array.

Comment: which field  hast to be in model bar it can be id or any other column you have in model bar ??

Answer (score 1):

You can simply Do it like this I am suggesting this because your question is unclear

```
foo.findAll({
    where: where,
    include: [{
        model: bar,
        where: { name: { [Op.is]: null } }
    }]
})
```

above code will return data of model bar where name as no value or the field is null